# Don't know how to create ISeq from clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure, hashmap

I want to add the values from a map on clojure with the next code:

```
(letfn [(r [l a]
          (if (empty? l)
            a
            (if (map? l)
              (r (first(vals l)) (+ a (first (vals l))))
              (r (rest l) (+ a (first l))))))]
  (r {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} 0)
```

but I get the following error:

> IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:542)

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do with an example?  Also, the part `(first(vals l))` is missing a space after "first".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that in your code you are testing for `empty` on `l`, without being sure that `l` is a seq. You should look further in the stacktrace for that:

> Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long
>
> ```
>                RT.java:  528  clojure.lang.RT/seqFrom
>                RT.java:  509  clojure.lang.RT/seq
>               core.clj:  137  clojure.core/seq
>               core.clj: 5948  clojure.core/empty?      <------
>                   REPL:   13  user/eval19330/r
>                   REPL:   16  user/eval19330/r
>                   REPL:   21  user/eval19330
> ```

This happens because `(first (vals l))` that is passed as the `l` parameter to the next iteration is a number and not a seq, in your case it is simply the value `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `r` can only handle collections (as you call `empty?` and then test on `map?` and otherwise call `rest`). You probably want to recurse like this:

```
(letfn [(r [l a]
          (if (empty? l)
            a
            (if (map? l)
              (let [[key val] (first l)]
                (r (dissoc l key) (+ a val)))
              (r (rest l) (+ a (first l))))))]
  (list (r {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} 0)
        (r [1 2 3] 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give the same error:

```
(empty? (first (vals {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})))
```

Also

```
(empty? 2)
```

Also

```
(concat [3] 2 [4])
```